# Error: QuoteContentController Compile Error: Invalid identifier: gmod__Product at line 56 column 21

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, wrapper-class, quote

I have created a vf page on "Quote" object .Now i would like to get the fields of custom object "OpportunityForecast" API name as gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c . This custom object does not have any relation ship with quote object .How to get the fields of this custom object in vf page .Written a wrapper class .But when i refer them the system throws an

Error: QuoteContentController Compile Error: Invalid identifier: gmod__Product at line 56 column 21

gmod__Product  field is a lookup field to Product object.

Similarly it throws an Error For gmod__Quantity and gmod__Price as an invalid identifier.

Is it that im making any blunder mistake in this code.I shall appreciate your help.Any suggestion plz.

**VF PAGE :**

```
<h2>OpportunityForecast Details</h2>
 <table class="bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0"> Part Numbers</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Quantity</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Price</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <apex:repeat value="{!disp_list}" var="opf">
            <tr>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod__Product}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod__Quantity}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod__Price }"/></td>
             </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**APEX CODE :**

```
public with sharing class QuoteContentController {

    public List<wrapperClass> disp_list {get;set;}

    public Competitor__c com{get;set;}

    public Id qId {get;set;}

    public QuoteContentController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    qId=Apexpages.currentPage().getparameters().get('Id');

    }
   //Declare a wrapper class  

     public class Wrapperclass{

     public gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c oppf{get;set;}

    //custom wrapper datatype  

      public string Name{get;set;}  
      public string AccountType{get;set;}  
      public date todaysDate{get;set;}  
      public date Expected_Order_Date{get;set;}
      public string Probability{get;set;}  
      public string Internal_Comment{get;set;}  
      public string External_Comment{get;set;}  

      public string Segment{get;set;}  
      public string Application{get;set;}  
      public string Persona{get;set;}  
      public string Geogrpahy{get;set;}  

      public string PartNumbers{get;set;}  
      public Decimal  Price{get;set;}  
      public Decimal End_Customer_Price{get;set;}  
      public Decimal Quantity {get;set;}  
      public Decimal Total{get;set;}  

      public string RFQ_justification{get;set;}  
      public string Main_Customer_of_Account{get;set;}  
      public string Bridgelux_competition_at_account{get;set;}
      public string Geographic_regions_serviced{get;set;}  
      public string Annual_lighting_revenue{get;set;}  
      public string Annual_LED_revenue_or_percent{get;set;}  
      public string Annual_purchases_of_LED_light_sources{get;set;}
      public string Percent_of_LED_purchases_that_are_COB{get;set;}  
      public string Other_information{get;set;}  

      public string Product_Series{get;set;}  
      public string Volume{get;set;} 
      public string Date_Price_is_Valid{get;set;} 

      ***Public string gmod__Product{get;set;}***
      Public Decimal gmod__Quantity{get;set;}
      Public Decimal gmod__Price{get;set;}

      public wrapperClass(){} 

  }
    public QuoteContentController(){

    //define constructor to instantiate the wrapper data type 

      disp_list=new list<wrapperclass>();

    //Query all the list 

     list<Quote> q =[select id ,Name ,Effective_Date__c ,Comments__c ,
                    Quote.Opportunity.Probability ,Quote.Opportunity.AccSegment__c ,Quote.Opportunity.AccApplication__c,Quote.Opportunity.Persona__c,Quote.Opportunity.Region__c
                    from Quote where id=:apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id')];

    list<QuoteLineItem> qli =[Select QuoteId , PricebookEntry.Product2.Name ,Unitprice ,End_Customer_Price__c ,Quantity , TotalPrice from QuoteLineItem where QuoteId =:qId ];

    list<Account> a = [Select id ,Name ,Main_Customers_of_Account__c ,Bridgelux_Competition_at_Account__c,Servicing_Region__c ,
                      Annual_LED_Revenue__c,Annual_Purchases_of_LED_Sources_SAM__c ,Percent_of_LED_purchases_that_are_COB__c from Account where account.id =:qId ];

   list<Competitor__c>  com = [Select id ,Part_Number__c,Product_Series__c,Price_Offered__c,Volume__c,Date_Price_is_Valid__c from Competitor__c  where Competitorid=:qId]  ; 

   list<gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c>  opflist = [Select id ,gmod__Product__c,gmod__Quantity__c,gmod__Price__c from gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c  where createddate!=null order by name limit 1 ]; 

       //Iterate through each list to extract the values and add it to the custom wrapper data type  

         for (Quote qt :q){

            for(integer i=0;i<opflist.size();i++){

                //Instantiating the wrapper SObject 

                wrapperclass w = new wrapperclass();

  //Assigning the wrapper variables from the SObject Fields in the database. 

  w.gmod__Product = opflist[i].gmod__Product__c;

  w.gmod__Quantity =opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c;

  w.gmod__Price=opflist[i].gmod__Price;

  w.Name =opflist[i].Name;

      //Adding everthing to the List  
     disp_list.add(w);

     w.name =qt.name;

      disp_list.add(w);

       }
     }
   }  
 } //End of Class
```

Comment: Which is line 56?

Comment: @Prady :Public string gmod__Product{get;set;}
gmod__Product field is a lookup field to Product object.
Similarly it throws an Error For gmod__Quantity and gmod__Price as an invalid identifier.

Comment: if you can mark which gives the error in the code , it would be easier for us to check it out

Comment: @Prady: ***Public string gmod__Product{get;set;}*** ,i have highlighted with the ***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the double underscore when naming a variable. Change it to anything but a double underscore.

I could not find the one for variable names but it follows this same rule for class names:

> The Apex class name. The name can only contain characters, letters, and the underscore (_) character, must start with a letter, and cannot end with an underscore or contain two consecutive underscore characters. This field is inherited from the Metadata component.